# How could I paralelize this function with OpenMP without race conditions nor false sharing?

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I need to paralelize one funcion without race conditions nor false sharing. I have tried many ways but I could not achieve that yet. The function is:

```
__inline static
void calculateClusterCentroIDs(int numCoords, int numObjs, int numClusters, float * dataSetMatrix, int * clusterAssignmentCurrent, float *clustersCentroID) {
    int * clusterMemberCount = (int *) calloc (numClusters,sizeof(float));

    // sum all points
    // for every point
    for (int i = 0; i < numObjs; ++i) {
        // which cluster is it in?
        int activeCluster = clusterAssignmentCurrent[i];

        // update count of members in that cluster
        ++clusterMemberCount[activeCluster];

        // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
        for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
            clustersCentroID[activeCluster*numCoords + j] += dataSetMatrix[i*numCoords + j];
    }


    // now divide each coordinate sum by number of members to find mean/centroid
    // for each cluster
    for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; ++i) {
        if (clusterMemberCount[i] != 0)
            // for each coordinate
            for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
                clustersCentroID[i*numCoords + j] /= clusterMemberCount[i];  /// XXXX will divide by zero here for any empty clusters!
    }
```

Any idea how could I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: *What* have you tried and how did it no work? What is a "career condition"?

Comment: That means: Some threads enter to a position for writtig a data It can be solved with atomic or critical or changing secuential code for avoid it

Comment: And I have tried many ways. I can say all of them. Basically I have tried change sequential code adding +1 dimension of each variable and then reduce it. I mean: (seq:)int *myVar; (omp:) int **myVar --> (sec:) myVar[i]; (omp:) myVar[omp_get_thread_num()][i]

Comment: So you mean race condition, or data race sometimes also called hazard. But I have never had it referred to has career condition. Have you tried the easiest: adding `omp parallel for` to the first inner, and the second outer loop?

Comment: Yes, also have tried it. But I did not get expected result (it should be 300, but I get other nums). Oh, ok, I will update question with 'race conditions', thank you.

Comment: You need to separate the histogram forming out of the first loop. After that, the loops will parallelize.

Comment: Can you show me an example? Now I do not know what is the histogram forming

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward

```
// sum all points
// for every point
for (int i = 0; i < numObjs; ++i) {
    // which cluster is it in?
    int activeCluster = clusterAssignmentCurrent[i];

    // update count of members in that cluster
    ++clusterMemberCount[activeCluster];

    // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
        clustersCentroID[activeCluster*numCoords + j] += dataSetMatrix[i*numCoords + j];
}
```

The inner loop is perfectly fine to parallelize as all writes happen to different elements of `clustersCentroID`. You can safely assume that the default schedule will not exhibit significant false sharing, it typically has large-enough chunks. Just **don't** try something like `schedule(static,1)`.

The outer loop is not as easy to parallelize. You could either use a reduction on `clusterMemberCount` and `clusterMemberCount`, or do something like:

```
#pragma omp parallel // note NO for
for (int i = 0; i < numObjs; ++i) {
    int activeCluster = clusterAssignmentCurrent[i];
    // ensure that exactly one thread works on each cluster
    if (activeCluster % omp_num_threads() != omp_get_thread_num()) continue;
```

Only do this if the simple solution does not yield sufficient performance.

The other loop is simple as well

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; ++i) {
    if (clusterMemberCount[i] != 0)
        // for each coordinate
        for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
            clustersCentroID[i*numCoords + j] /= clusterMemberCount[i];
}
```

Again, data access is perfectly isolated both in terms of correctness and, except for edge cases, false sharing.

Comment: parallelizing the first outer loop with `if (activeCluster % omp_num_threads() != omp_get_thread_num()) continue;` will distribute every other value of `activeCluster` to a different thread. This will result in some false sharing when writing on `clusterAssignmentCurrent`, and potentially also when writing on `clustersCentroID` if there are not that many dimensions (the edge effect will become significant if `numCoords` is small, i.e. it the exact case when parallelizing  the inner loop is not efficient).

Comment: You are right, but I did not want to make assumptions about `numCoords`. The simple approach is fine until you know more about the values and/or measurements show that it is too slow. I only try to sketch the direction for parallelizing the outer loop - reduction is usually advisable. You can use any sophisticated distribution of clusters to threads.

Answer (score 1):

You should give an order of magnitude for the expected values of `numCoords`, `numObjs` and `numClusters` as the optimal way to parallelize depends on that. Especially, `numCoords` is important to see if parallelizing/vectorizing the inner loop over coordinates makes sense; like, are you taking of 3D coordinates or 1000 dimensions?

Another attempt with the drawback of an `if` statement in the first loop (bad for performance), static schedule (possible load unbalance) but each thread incrementing contiguous parts of `clusterMemberCount` and `clustersCentroID` which limits the risk of false sharing.

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
   #include <omp.h>
#else
   #define omp_get_num_threads() 1
   #define omp_get_thread_num() 0
#endif


__inline static
void calculateClusterCentroIDs(int numCoords, int numObjs, int numClusters, float * dataSetMatrix, int * clusterAssignmentCurrent, float *clustersCentroID) {
    int * clusterMemberCount = (int *) calloc (numClusters,sizeof(float));
    // sum all points
    // for every point

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int nbOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int thisThread = omp_get_thread_num();
        // Schedule for the first step : process only cluster with ID in the [from , to[ range
        int clustFrom = (thisThread*numClusters)/nbOfThreads;
        int clustTo   = (thisThread+1 == nbOfThreads) ? numClusters : ((thisThread+1)*numClusters)/nbOfThreads;

        // Each thread will loop through all values of numObjs but only process them depending on activeCluster
        // The loop is skipped only if the thread was assigned no cluster
        if (clustTo>clustFrom){
            for (int i = 0; i < numObjs; ++i) {
                // which cluster is it in?
                int activeCluster = clusterAssignmentCurrent[i];

                if (activeCluster>=clustFrom && activeCluster<clustTo){
                    // update count of members in that cluster
                    ++clusterMemberCount[activeCluster];

                    // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
                    for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
                        clustersCentroID[activeCluster*numCoords + j] += dataSetMatrix[i*numCoords + j];
                }
            }
        }

        #pragma omp barrier

        // now divide each coordinate sum by number of members to find mean/centroid
        // for each cluster
        #pragma omp for // straightforward
        for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; ++i) {
            if (clusterMemberCount[i] != 0)
                // for each coordinate
                for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
                    clustersCentroID[i*numCoords + j] /= clusterMemberCount[i];  /// XXXX will divide by zero here for any empty clusters!
        }
    }
    free(clusterMemberCount);
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach. The code snippet is mixing `clustFrom/To` and `clusterLimits`. You might want to consider `numClusters < nbOfThreads`.

Comment: You are right about the cluster limits & from/to , I edited the answer. The code should run fine even if `numClusters < nbOfThreads`. Of course, in that case, all threads but the last one will have `clustFrom==0` and `clustTo==0` and would loop for no reason...

Comment: I moved a bit the parentheses in `clustFrom` & `clustTo` definition for better load balancing, and added an `if` to skip the first loop if there is nothing to process, rather then loop and hit an `if(condition_always_false)`